# injecting javascript in mvc razor3 using values from the server side variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to call a jquery function on the view, using server side variable,
the variable are set in the viewbag without encoding the variables values.

eg.:

```
ViewBag.innerTitle = "<div id='title45'>My Title</div>"; //C#

$(function(){ alert(ViewBag.Title) }); // Js can I Access it
```

Comment: what are the templates engine razor or regular aspnet view ?

Comment: What do you expect as the output of that? Note in particular that .innerTitle and .Title are different - is that intentional? or a typo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, with that type of content I would be writing the html to the page, and just using jQuery, i.e.

```
alert($('#title45').text());
```

Then the js is fixed, ideal for use on a static .js file that is downloaded and cached separately.

If you must write it to dynamic js:

```
alert('@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(ViewBag.Title))');
```

but I would be nervous about single and double quotes.

Comment: Icant use it before sending the markup to the dom , since the html currently are stored in the viewbag ?

Comment: @JhonyHana can you rephrase that? it is hard to understand what you mean, not least because you haven't actually shown us an example of what `ViewBag.Title` contains, or what you expect the displayed text to be.

Comment: @MarcGravell Am I correct `JavaScriptStringEncode` is *always* to be paired with `Html.Raw` when generating dynamic js?

Answer (score 0):

if your are using razor:

simply in your js:

```
<script>$(function(){ alert(' @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Title) ') });</script>

@Html.Raw : output the markup w/o encoding it.
```